# Set navigation bar background image

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, navigationbar

This is my code:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "navigationbar")
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(logo!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0, bottom: 0 ,right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

But doesn't working. This is error code.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to see where your code is crashing .... its starting point .. then solve that part whose nil ... in your code either `navigationController` or `Image` is nil

```
if let logo = UIImage(named: "navigationbar") {
    if let navigation = self.navigationController {

       navigation.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(logo!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0, bottom: 0 ,right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
      }else {
        print("Navigation cotroller not found and its nil")
      }
} else {
   print("problem wiyh image file")
}
```

Comment: Ohh cool. Printed "Navigation cotroller not found and its nil". I'm beginner :((

Comment: Now you need to check why its nil

Comment: For that you need to post code ... where you are adding it?

Comment: I added your code in viewDidLoad() func. But I don't know how check why it's nil. Should I import Navigationbar?

Comment: Your controller is in navigation controler ?

Comment: I added permission in info.plist. It's working. OMG. But I appreciate what you did. Thank you so much. If you don't say, i didn't know everything. Good luck man

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is definitely not a navigation controller, if it is the first controller that you present in your app you must set it in scene delegate under willConnectTo function like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

if you call the controller with a button action set function that present navigation Controller like this:

```
@objc fileprivate func callNavigationController() {
let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourController())
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

now in viewDidLoad set the navigationBar background, 
first unwrap image with a guard let statement:

```
guard let logo = UIImage(named: "navigationbar") else { return }
```

after set navigation bar background image:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(logo.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0, bottom: 0 ,right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

And that's all